# Jquery:Unbind click event on the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using jQuery and i want to unbind the click event of dom element wherever a particular class is added to that dom element.

This particular class is added and removed dynamically using add class and remove class functions. So if the class is added on dom element and id that dom element has a click event i want to unbind the click event.

Comment: try `selector.off('click'); `

Comment: Sir sorry for asking this but reason i am asking this is because in this case I am dynamically loading the html and the class hence it becomes difficult to add selector to find the class and put unbind or off event. I wont something like delegates which can find the class on the document and do the required.

Comment: How do you bind the event handler in the first place? Are you using event delegation for that? In that case, update your selector like Elias suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to bind and unbind the event? It may be simpler to do something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#element:not(.someClass)", function () {
    // this function will only run if the clicked element doesn't have the class someClass
});
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$('.someClass').unbind('click');
```

or

```
$('.someClass').off('click');
```

You have the answer in your title.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the context here is. How do you bind it in the first place and why do you want to unbind it?

An alternative way is to just ignore the click event if the element has a certain class.

```
$(selector).on("click", function(event) {
    // Returning false will automatically call event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault()
    if ($(this).hasClass("some-class")) return;

    // Other code
});
```